# Spotify API (Android) issues

Tags: android, api, spotify

So, I need to create an app in android that can stream music.

I followed the `Spotify API` tutorial and was able to play one track like its suppose to.

The problem is I need more than just one track. How do I get more `URI's`?

> Example: spotify:track:2TpxZ7JUBn3uw46aR7qd6V

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to get track URIs. You could use the desktop application to find them - simply right click on a track and copy the URI to the clipboard.

You could also use the web API to find them. Any endpoint that returns tracks, e.g. [Retrieve a Track](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/get-track/), returns the track's URI in the `uri` attribute.